# Understand this .bashrc script (curly braces, eval, ...)

Tags: bash, eval, curly-braces

I have some difficulty understanding what is written in my ubuntu's `.bashrc` which is shown in part below.
Here is what I don't understand :

- What is the purpose of curly braces and the `-`/`+` symbols used after `:`? (ex. : ${debian_chroot:-} and ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)})
- The `eval` command.
- How the following snippet of code works.

  ```
  [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

  if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
      debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
  fi

  if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
      PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
  else
      PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
  fi
  ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`${var:-default}` means `$var if $var is defined and otherwise "default"`

`${var:+value}` means `if $var is defined use "value"; otherwise nothing`

The second one might seem a little wierd, but your code snippet shows a typical use:

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}
```

This means "if $debian_chroot is defined, then insert it inside parentheses."

Above, "defined" means "set to some non-null value". Unix shells typically don't distinguish between unset variables and variables set to an empty string, but bash can be told to raise an error condition if an unset variable is used. (You do this with `set -u`.) In this case, if `debian_chroot` has never been set, `$debian_chroot` will cause an error, while `${debian_chroot:-}` will use `$debian_chroot` if it has been set, and otherwise an empty string.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about subshells in parentheses. I also found this link which answers my questions : http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe . Still I find `${debian_chroot:-}` strange. Isn't it equivalent to simply `$debian_chroot`?

Comment: @Gradient If `set -u` is used, an attempt to use an unset variable will be treated as an error, rather than expanding to a null string. `${debian_chroot:-}` will explicitly expand an unset variable to the null string, avoiding that error.